# Python Dataframe GroupBy Function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I am having hard time understanding what the code below does. I initially thought it was counting the unique appearances of the values in (weight age) and (weight height) however when I ran this example, I found out it was doing something else.

```
data = [[0,33,15,4],[1,44,12,3],[0,44,12,5],[1,33,15,4],[0,77,13,4],[1,33,15,4],[1,99,40,7],[0,58,45,4],[1,11,13,4]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=["Lbl","Weight","Age","Height"])
print (df)

def group_fea(df,key,target):
    '''
    Adds columns for feature combinations
    '''
    tmp = df.groupby(key, as_index=False)[target].agg({
        key+target + '_nunique': 'nunique',
    }).reset_index()
    del tmp['index']
    print("****{}****".format(target))
    return tmp


#Add feature combinations
feature_key = ['Weight']
feature_target = ['Age','Height']
for key in feature_key:
    for target in feature_target:
        tmp = group_fea(df,key,target)
        df = df.merge(tmp,on=key,how='left')

print (df) 
      Lbl  Weight  Age  Height
0    0      33   15       4
1    1      44   12       3
2    0      44   12       5
3    1      33   15       4
4    0      77   13       4
5    1      33   15       4
6    1      99   40       7
7    0      58   45       4
8    1      11   13       4
****Age****
****Height****
   Lbl  Weight  Age  Height  WeightAge_nunique  WeightHeight_nunique
0    0      33   15       4                  1                     1
1    1      44   12       3                  1                     2
2    0      44   12       5                  1                     2
3    1      33   15       4                  1                     1
4    0      77   13       4                  1                     1
5    1      33   15       4                  1                     1
6    1      99   40       7                  1                     1
7    0      58   45       4                  1                     1
8    1      11   13       4                  1                     1
```

I want to understand what the values in WeightAge_nunique  WeightHeight_nunique mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of `WeightAge_nunique` on a given row is the number of unique Ages that have the same Weight. The corresponding thing is true of `WeightHeight_nunique`. E.g., for people of Weight=44, there is only 1 unique age (12), hence `WeightAge_nunique=1` on those rows, but there are 2 unique Heights (3 and 5), hence `WeightHeight_nunique=2` on those same rows.

You can see that this happens because the grouping function groups by the "key" column (Weight), then performs the "nunique" aggregation function on the "target" column (either Age or Height).

Answer (score 0):

Let us try `transform`

```
g = df.groupby('Weight').transform('nunique')
df['WeightAge_nunique'] = g['Age']
df['WeightHeight_nunique'] = g['Height']
df
Out[196]: 
   Lbl  Weight  Age  Height  WeightAge_nunique  WeightHeight_nunique
0    0      33   15       4                  1                     1
1    1      44   12       3                  1                     2
2    0      44   12       5                  1                     2
3    1      33   15       4                  1                     1
4    0      77   13       4                  1                     1
5    1      33   15       4                  1                     1
6    1      99   40       7                  1                     1
7    0      58   45       4                  1                     1
8    1      11   13       4                  1                     1
```